# MSSQL connection string - Windows Authentication using another set of credentials

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, authentication, odbc

It doesn't seem possible to craft a connection string so that you can open a connection to a mssql server using another user's windows credentials.  It appears you are limited to specifying either a sql server account, or specifying no creds at all which passes along the current set being used on the domain.

**What workarounds are effective ways to circumvent this restriction?**

A bit of background:
The company I'm deploying at would like to set up windows credentials for each application accessing the shared databases.  This works well for daemon-like background tasks, but it seems a bit complicated for desktop applications.

I've been asked to NOT pass the users creds to the database, but instead pass a set of windows creds reserved for the application itself...  not sql server credentials, but an account on the domain for the application.

I've been contemplating using [Runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) to launch the application (written in Python) using this application windows account.

Perhaps someone out there can suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a domain group (active directory) for the application, then assign specific domain users to be in that group.  The I suppose you could grant privileges to the database for that group.

This would allow specific permissions to be controlled for the group.

Just a suggestion, I hope it helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Understandable...  Sometimes in order to succeed though, you need to tell the customer when it can't be done by their rules.  I really hate to say "can't" but some times the rules are just too unreasonable.  Good Luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to, in the connection string, specify an alternative set of Windows credentials.  Your instinct about runas is spot on.  I often use that to launch SSMS when connecting to a different domain than my laptop is on.  Good luck!

Comment: Too bad about that prompt though... starts to feel 'hacky', you know what I mean?